# How to fix One page layout

Tags: html, css

First is "header" second is "left menu" and third is "content block".
In this design I want to fix all blocks in one window so scroll-bar should not show. If in "content block" content is more then inside content block scroll-bar should come. 
I want to make design like given below image:
[image]

**The Code:**

```css
.main-container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  background:#eee;
}
header{
  background:#fff;
  height:70px;
}
.logo{
  background:#303f9f; 
  height:70px;
  width:250px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #1a237e;
  float:left;
}
.header-right{
  background:#fff; 
  height:70px;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 250px); 
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  float:left
}
.left-menu{ 
  font-size:20px;
  background:#3f51b5; 
  height:100%;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
.content-block{
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 250px);
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:auto; 
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:right
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class=header-right>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="left-menu">
    left navigation
  </div>
  <div class="content-block">
    content block
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use following code

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var winHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
  $('.content-block').css('height',winHeight);
});
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.content-block{
  overflow:auto;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Using js will give window height to content box because can be different with different devices so height will manage according to screen height and overflow auto will show scroll if needed.

Comment: but how to fix the layout @gauravaggarwal. Check my code snippet, first let me know how to fix layout

Comment: use this css property in content-block `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: this property will merge the extra padding with width and it will fix the error

Comment: but the scroll bar is still coming

Comment: ya thanks @gauravAggarwal this what I was looking for. I will add everything in code snippet. So it will be good for other people also

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```css
.main-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
}
header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
}
.logo {
  background: #303f9f;
  height: 70px;
  width: 250px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a237e;
  float: left;
}
.header-right {
  background: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 250px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  float: left
}
.left-menu {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #3f51b5;
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 70px);
  height: -ms-calc(100% - 70px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 70px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 70px);
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top:70px;
}
.content-block {
  left: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 270px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 270px);
  width: -ms-calc(100% - 270px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 270px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 270px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class=header-right>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="left-menu">
    left navigation

  </div>
  <div class="content-block">
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    con
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    vgjklnnlk
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    onyyubnjbj
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
    content block
     <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is this answer all about...where is the solved problem?

Comment: I think you near to answer. but scrollbar is still coming. I want scroll in content block only. rest of the layout should be fixed @moishelipsker

Comment: @AjayMalhotra I added additional changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your CSS, .content-block the width is not calculate right becouse of your padding options in the same class

```css
.main-container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  background:#eee;
}
header{
  background:#fff;
  height:70px;
}
.logo{
  background:#303f9f; 
  height:70px;
  width:250px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #1a237e;
  float:left;
}
.header-right{
  background:#fff; 
  height:70px;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 250px); 
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  float:left
}
.left-menu{ 
  font-size:20px;
  background:#3f51b5; 
  height:calc(100% - 72px);
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
.content-block{
  height:calc(100% - 72px);
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 250px);
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto; 
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:right
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class=header-right>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="left-menu">
    left navigation
  </div>
  <div class="content-block">
    content block
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please write the code in code snippet. It will be better

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is in given below code snippet.

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.main-container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%; 
  background:#eee;
}
header{
  background:#fff;
  height:70px;
}
.logo{
  background:#303f9f; 
  height:70px;
  width:250px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #1a237e;
  float:left;
}
.header-right{
  background:#fff; 
  height:70px;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 250px); 
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  float:left
}
.left-menu{ 
  font-size:20px;
  background:#3f51b5; 
  height:100%;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
}
.content-block{
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-o-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-ms-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-webkit-calc(100% - 250px);
  width:-moz-calc(100% - 250px);
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:auto; 
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:right;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <header>
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class=header-right>

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </header>
  <div class="left-menu">
    left navigation

  </div>
  <div class="content-block">
    content block<br>
    content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>content block<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/c2pjj14u/1/).**

Just Fixed by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.left-menu` and `.content-block` to calculate their width and height **excluding** the padding .

Note: i gave the `.left-menu` and `.content-block` padding top with header height value to show the content.

**OR:**
You can consider the padding with the inner width. ex: `width:calc(100% - 270px);` instead of `width:calc(100% - 250px);` as it has `10px` of padding .